# x axis is too short in R plot.default

Tags: r, plot, axis

My x axis is too short.

[image: My Plot]

```
d <- data.frame(x = c(120,200,300), y = rep(1,3))

 plot(d$x, 
      d$y,
      xlim = c(min(d$x), max(d$x)),
      axes = FALSE,
      xlab = "",
      ylab = "")

axis(1, lwd = 2)
```

Clearly this is not ideal.  I know there are numerous solutions for a single instance of plotting.  However, I'm programmatically generating numerous of such graphs with difference x values.  I therefore need a solution which is general and is directly applicable to different x values.

Below is some brain-storming code:

```
 #This works but the tick marks are ugly.  I also can't control lwd of axis
 plot(d$x, 
      d$y,
      yaxt="n",
      frame.plot = FALSE,
      xlab = "",
      ylab = "",
      xaxp = c(120, 300, 50)) 

 #this is the solution for this particular case, however, it would not work in general
 plot(d$x, 
      d$y,
      xlim = c(min(d$x)-20, max(d$x)),
      axes = FALSE,
      xlab = "",
      ylab = "")

axis(1, lwd = 2)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `I also can't control lwd of axis` as you sure? that's a pretty blanket statement. did you try `lwd` in `axis`? since you've only given one example, i can only provide you with this `with(d, plot(x, y, axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)); axis(1, at = pretty(range(d$x)), lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)` not sure how this would work for you in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method using base R graphics. The logic is similar to the `ggplot2` answer. The code below sets the x-range to the nearest multiples of 50 below and above the range of the data and puts ticks marks at every multiple of 50. You can add fancier logic if you want to vary either of these dynamically, based on the range of the data for different plots.

`xfun` calculates the minimum and maximum x-limits. `tick.dist` sets the distance we want between tick marks in the graph. The default is set to 50. So, by default, when `which="min"`, `xfun` returns the largest multiple of 50 that is less than `value`. When `which="max"`, `xfun` returns the large multiple of 50 that is greater than `value`.

```
xfun = function(value, which, tick.dist=50) {

  # Calculate minimum x-limit
  if(which=="min") {
    return(value - value %% tick.dist)
  }

  # Calculate maximum x-limit
  if(which=="max") {
    return(value + (tick.dist - value %% tick.dist))
  }
}
```

Now we create four sample plots.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

# Try out various ranges for the x-values
x_vals = c(-23, 56, 80, 123)

# Set distance between tick marks
tick.dist=50

for (i in 1:length(x_vals)) {
  # Create fake data
  d <- data.frame(x=runif(10, x_vals[i], x_vals[i] + 220), y = rep(3,10))  

  # Set x limits and number of tick marks
  xmin = xfun(min(d$x), "min", tick.dist) 
  xmax = xfun(max(d$x), "max", tick.dist) 
  nticks = as.integer((xmax - xmin)/tick.dist)

  # Plot
  plot(d$x, d$y, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", frame.plot = FALSE,
       xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim=c(xmin, xmax)) 

  # xaxp controls location of min and max x-axis tick marks
  #  as well as the total number of tick marks. 
  #  See ?par("xaxp") for more info.
  axis(1, lwd = 2, xaxp = c(xmin, xmax, nticks))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that uses `ggplot2` for the plotting. The code below sets the x-range to the nearest multiples of 50 below and above the range of the data and puts ticks marks at every multiple of 50. You can add fancier logic if you want to vary either of these dynamically, based on the range of the data for different plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)  # For grid.arrange function
```

`xfun` calculates the minimum and maximum x-limits. `tick.dist` sets the distance we want between tick marks in the graph. The default is set to 50. So, by default, when `which="min"`, `xfun` returns the largest multiple of 50 that is less than `value`. When `which="max"`, `xfun` returns the large multiple of 50 that is greater than `value`.

```
xfun = function(value, which, tick.dist=50) {

  # Calculate lower x-limit
  if(which=="min") {
    return(value - value %% tick.dist)
  }

  # Calculate upper x-limit
  if(which=="max") {
    return(value + (tick.dist - value %% tick.dist))
  }
}
```

Now we create a custom theme that plots only the point markers and the x-axis:

```
my_theme = list(theme_bw(),
                theme(panel.border=element_blank(), 
                      axis.line=element_line(), 
                      axis.line.y=element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
                      axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
                      axis.text.y=element_blank()),
                labs(y="",x=""))
```

Now we create plots for four different sets of x-values, using `xfun` to set the x-limits.

```
# Try out various ranges for the x-values
x_vals = c(-23, 56, 80, 123)

# Set distance between ticks and x-axis padding
tick.dist=50
pad = 5

# List to store the plots
p.list=list()

# Create a plot for each element of x_vals
for (i in 1:length(x_vals)) {

  # Create fake data
  d <- data.frame(x=runif(10, x_vals[i], x_vals[i] + 220), y = rep(3,10))  

  # Set x limits
  xmin = xfun(min(d$x), "min", tick.dist) 
  xmax = xfun(max(d$x), "max", tick.dist) 

  # Plot
  p.list[[i]] = ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    # Set the exact x-axis range
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(xmin - pad, xmax + pad)) + 
    # Set major tick values
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-1000,1000, tick.dist)) +
    my_theme
}

# Plot all the graphs on a single "page"
do.call(grid.arrange, p.list)
```

[image]